# Django: How to access the model id's within an AJAX script?

Tags: django

I was wondering what is the correct approach,

Do I create HiddenInput fields in my ModelForm and from the
    View I pass in the primaryKey for the models I am about to edit into
    the hiddenInput fields and then grab those hiddenInput fields from
    the AJAX script to use it like this?

```
item.load(
        "/bookmark/save/" + hidden_input_field_1,
        null,
        function () {
          $("#save-form").submit(bookmark_save);
        }
);
```

Or is there is some more clever way of doing it and I have no idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just asked in the django IRC room and it says:

> since js isn't processed by the django template engine, this is not
>   possible.

Hence the id or the object passed in from django view can't be accessed within AJAX script.

Answer (score 0):

It depends upon how you want to implement.
The basic idea is to edit 1. you need to get the existing instance, 2. Save provided information into this object.

For #1 you can do it multiple ways, like passing `ID` or any other primary key like attribute in url like `http://myserver/edit_object/1` , Or pass `ID` as hidden input then you have to do  it through templates.

For #2, I think you would already know this. Do something like

```
inst = MyModel.objects.get(id=input_id) # input_id taken as per #1
myform = MyForm(request.POST, instance=inst)
if myform.is_valid():
    saved_inst = myform.save()
```

Comment: Thanks Rohan, but within the jquery js file, how do I access my IDs? would I be able to access {{form.contact_id}} from javascript file?

Comment: @Kave If you are rendering as form field, it will be present in the form, so you can get it from the form you received.